# Connecting to AD with LDAP in Python - Error 'unable to open socket', [(LDAPSocketOpenError("('socket ssl wrapping error: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3895)'

Tags: python, ssl, ldap, ssl-certificate

When connecting to MS-AD to perform a password reset using the following Python script with LDAP3 library and SSL protocol, I am facing a problem connecting.

```
import ldap3 as ldap
import ssl

# <-------------------------------Adicionar Certificado a coneção----------------------------------->
certificado = "<certificado>.cer"
context = ssl.create_default_context()

#tls = Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_NONE)
tls = ldap.Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL , version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS, local_certificate_file=certificado)

#------------------------------< Variavel AE >---------------#
dominio = ldap.Server('TESTE.LOCAL', 636, tls=tls, get_info=ldap.ALL, use_ssl=True)
user='<usuario>'
pwd='<pass>'
usuarioDN = '<user for reset>'
newPass = '<new pass>'

# <--------------------------------Conexão com AD LDAP com autenticação----------------------------------->
connect = ldap.Connection(server=dominio, 
                        user=user, 
                        password=pwd, 
                        read_only = True, 
                        auto_bind=True,
                        version=3,
                        authentication='SIMPLE')


print(connect)

# <------------------------------Realizar a alteração da Senha------------------------------------->
connect.extend.microsoft.modify_password(usuarioDN, newPass)
print(connect.result)

# <-------------------------------Exigir troca de senha no próximo Logon --------------------------------------------->
connect.modify(usuarioDN,{"pwdLastSet":(ldap.MODIFY_REPLACE, 0)})
print(connect.result)
```

As it is a secure server, a certificate is required to authenticate the connection, where I have already performed the tests both by installing the certificate on the server where the script is running and also informing the certificate in the code.

Still it always returns the error as below.

```
Exception has occurred: LDAPSocketOpenError
('unable to open socket', [(LDAPSocketOpenError("('socket ssl wrapping error: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3895)',)"), ('***.***.***.***', 636)), (LDAPSocketOpenError("('socket ssl wrapping error: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3895)',)"), ('***.***.***.***', 636)), (LDAPSocketOpenError("('socket ssl wrapping error: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3895)',)"), ('***.***.***.***', 636)), (LDAPSocketOpenError("('socket ssl wrapping error: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3895)',)"), ('***.***.***.***', 636)), (LDAPSocketOpenError("('socket ssl wrapping error: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3895)',)"), ('***.***.***.***', 636))])
  File "C:\Users\sv_eyeshare\Desktop\TPLDAP\ResetSenhaLdap.py", line 19, in <module>
```

Has anyone faced this problem that can help me please.